Is there a way for someone to say something in such a way that it would be a jailable offence to lie?
I was thinking about how for many types of insurance claims, you have to attach a police report. So if you had an expensive watch, and it got stolen, you can get paid by your insurance, but you have to submit a police report of it being stolen. The idea is that if you wanted to lie to get insurance money, if caught, not only would it be fraud, but also filing a false police report, which is a bad crime. (not just normal theft insurance, but also Airbnb, if you lose your Swiss passport, if you lose your suitcase)
(I know that this is an overkill, but) Let's say that I was late to work and I wanted to prove to my boss that I was honest about the bus not arriving when it should have. Is there something that I can do to claim that the bus didn't arrive. But, make the claim so strong, that if I'm caught lying I can be jailed?
This is for a story, so any interesting country's law is okay.

What if your boss fired you for being late, but you then sued him for unfair dismissal, and swore in court that the only reason you were late was the bus had not arrived?

You use the tag "perjury", but in many legal systems that term is much narrower and a bit to the side of the question you are asking. You may wish to remove the tag or adjust the question to clarify that the lie is taking place under oath/in an official proceeding, if that is what you mean.

@JayMcEh by having received an answer that relies on the tag, removal or addition of information upon which (or their absence) answers relied would be a violation of the don't shift the goalpost rule.

@Trish Laymen don't always understand the terminology, it seems wrong to nullify the question due to a simple mistake like that when it can easily be fixed.

@Trish, Adding or removing tags is neither a nullification, nor "moving the goal posts".  Tags simply allow someone to narrow down and group relevant and similar questions.  Since perjury is relevant in this case a tag is appropriate, but removing it doesn't negate a good answer, because the answer should address the question, not a particular tag.  (Editing the question in a way that invalidates an answer is a more egregious faux pas.)  If you feel strongly otherwise, just add the tag back in...

The problem is that your boss does not have the ability to jail you, and I find it unlikely they'd convince the local district attorney to prosecute and jail you for such an inconsequential lie, either. The threat of a severe but vanishingly unlikely punishment doesn't give your statement much additional credibility. Saying you'll go to jail if found to be lying is a bit like saying you'll give the boss a billion dollars, or that you'll eat your hat if found to be lying. It's a nice sentiment, but we all know it's never going to happen.

Not a law frame challenge so I'll leave this as a comment: If this is for a story, could you not write something in to make such a law exist in your world, if it feels right to you that this would happen in said world?

@user3490 not sure how jailing someone for directing a terror group is similar.

@LioElbammalf I could make up a law, but that's less fun

@NuclearHoagie Just a note, the concept of private prosecution does exist in some jurisdictions, where just about anyone is able to start criminal proceedings.

See also: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/when-is-it-illegal-to-lie/27422#27422

The most common ways to convert a written statement into the criminal offense of perjury are to have someone prepare either a statement made under an oath administered by a suitable official (usually a notary) called an "affidavit", or a statement that says it is made under penalty of perjury (without an official presiding) which is usually called a "declaration".
In many contexts (including filings in federal courts and in the courts of Utah and Colorado, for example), affidavits and declarations filed in court are equivalent in effect. In other contexts, such as filings in real estate records, affidavits are legally effective, but declarations are not.
Of course, in many cases, lying about a material matter with an intent to personally gain from doing so is a criminal offense, such as "fraud" even if it is not contained in an affidavit or declaration. Often there are a mix of laws that criminalize particular kinds of false statements not made under oath (e.g. false police reports) and a general criminal fraud statute.

So it would have to be a court case? Could I do something simple such as sue my boss (with his guidance) for not giving me a raise. Then submit a statement saying that my bus never arrived, but since that's not my fault, I should get a raise. Then close the case (eg. reach a settlement of $0). I guess in that case it would only cost court fees (about $1k?).

@finks You comment here makes no sense. You can submit a statement saying that you were late because of a bus. But so what? I don't understand the talk of a raise, or settlement, or whatever you're going on about.

@finks You're asking multiple questions that go beyond the scope of your original. If answerers raise new points of curiosity (as this one appears to have), you can search the archives for explanations and ask new questions if there are areas that remain unclear. Keeping the topics focused and specific helps each question be a good resource for other future searchers like yourself!

Prelude
This was tagged perjury. Perjury is extremely narrow. To be perjury, a statement needs to be in an official proceeding, and even then, there are usually quite high hurdles. As a general rule of thumb what is considered perjury in most jurisdictions, you

need to be a sworn or otherwise informed witness in a case,
your testimony needs to be material and
you need to deliberately tell a the untruth.

germany
In general, a witness is not sworn in but is only demanded to tell the truth under threat of punishment for "uneidliche Falschaussage" § 153 StGB (unsworn wrong testimony) with 3 months to 5 years of jail hanging over the head.
If the testimony is put into question or super highly material, the witness can be sworn in (vereidigt) and then saying anything that isn't the whole truth is perjury (Meineid, § 154 StGB). Punishment here is *at least a year if convicted, no upper limit given. As no maximum length is set in the paragraph, the general maximum punishment (§ 38 StGB) of 15 years the statute of limitations being 20 years (§ 78 Abs. 3 Nr. 2 StGB).
Setup
So, we need to make it absolutely material that your excuse to the boss becomes impeached to the point you are put under oath in a trial...
Let's say you tell your boss you are late because you helped in an accident on Route A while you were actually taking route B and were just late. Your Boss just happens to have heard the news that the police is looking for the lone samaritan that helped there to try to identify the runaway driver that caused the accident on Route A.
The boss instructs you, that you are given free time to report that to the police on his dime, because he wants the driver found. You make a report of a neon green opel Tigra with racing stripes and invent one digit of the number plate. By happenstance the police finds a matching car that just happened to be on Route A in roughly the right timeframe as the driver was staying somewhere in the the area. The police makes the arrest and they manage to find enough evidence to bring charges for "negligent killing".
The court calls you as a witness, you testify the same thing as to the police, but things don't seem to match up with the other testimony and experts. So you are put under oath and claim it was clearly defendant who did the drive by. Defendant is convicted for that 'evidence' for negligent killing while driving and punished for 5 years under § 222 StGB.
Some years after the trial, someone boasts in a bar on Route A that they once drove so reckless and high, right out of the door of the bar, in their vintage blue Buik 8, that another car rammed a tree and burst into flames while a second escaped just in time. The bar owner calls in the police and the guy is arrested. He gleefully repeats his testimony at the station. Obviously, the pissed prosecutor hears of this, brings a Wiederaufnahmeverfahren to fix the injustice against the Tigra-driver and have him declared innocent (and compensated), and then files charges against both the Buik 8 driver: murder against the driver, because his depraved mind, and you for perjury under oath, which resulted in someone innocent getting jailed and deprived of rights.
The car that avoided the Buik driver? Well, that was the good samaritan. If you need a reason why he never was found: police thought you were the helper. But after helping the samaritan drove into the sunset to be never seen again (and probably never heard of the case).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
